# Xamarin – Error Fixing “The Aapt task failed unexpectedly”

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am facing issue when i re build or build my droid project. I have updated my Android SDK but issue still is in my solution. Please suggest me how to remove this issue.
[image]

I have tried many solution which are on google but issue still come up.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio (or computer itself)?

Comment: Yes i have already tried this process. i have already deleted all the temp files from system but issue still is in solution.

Comment: Do you have any files in `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools` or your custom `ANDROID_SDK_PATH/build-tools` folder?

Comment: Yes i have many file in this sections

Comment: do you have a duplicate layout(or any) file in your resource files?

Comment: No, Duplicate will not be added if you will try to add same file it will give the error pop of duplicate and i already cross check this point in my solution and there is no duplicate file

Comment: referring to this post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39861/latest-update-aapt-task-failed-unexpectedly

Answer (score 15):

For me, giving 2.1 in Version Number property of the Project Properties gave this error. So after changing it to 2, the project built successfully. 
[image: highlighted error]

Comment: I'm giving this answer a vote up because this is also a solution to the "The "Aapt" task failed unexpectedly - Input string was not in a correct format". Thank you, Rakesh.

Comment: The version number (versionCode) must be an [integer](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html)! That explains it

Answer (score 2):

As referring to above mentioned Post by Milen Pavlov i.e :
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39861/latest-update-aapt-task-failed-unexpectedly.

It looks that your Droid CS.Proj containing two references of a same file. So, open it on Notepad and identify the duplicate reference carefully and remove that.

OR

If you have any recent backup of your project then you can Compare Droid CS.Proj with existing Droid CS.Proj to filter new changes and then identify duplicate reference.

Answer (score 0):

I remember Once I faced this problem a few days ago after I'd added an image to the resources folder which its name was `shopping_card.png`. I renamed the image to `shoppingcard.png` (removing -) and problem resolved.

In your case also I think something is wrong with resources. Have you ever add a new resource lately? Try to remove them, clean and then rebuild project hope this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We eventually solved this issue, passing through some other errors that might happen (or not) according to your own environment.

There is this old Android bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80808

This implies that Google had the bug in the older Android SDK build-tools versions (and hopefully they fixed it as mentioned in the above URL).
Anyhow, the error message likely explains why; it is likely because your main dex file does not contain necessary multidex support classes.

One possible cause of the problem is your dx.jar might be old and have the issue mentioned above. Assuming you have fairly up-to-date Xamarin.Android, try installling the latest "build-tools" Android SDK component and remove older versions.

Or, instead of removing old SDK build-tools, add AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion build property to the .csproj file within some active  :

```
<AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>23.0.1</AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>
```

In my case this raised other errors that I solved using **JDK 1.8**

After that I encountered the following Xamarin Bug ([The option for multi-dex fails when the path to the Android SDK contains a space](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33052)
) that can be solved locating the android-sdk in a path without spaces (so for example c:\program files(x86)\android\android-sdk is not a valid location)

You might also see an error due to **m2Repository** path that can be solved thanks to the info at the following link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Bear in mind that you might need to add/update/remove the Android-sdk packages/version. Here what worked for me.

[image]

Items stroke in red are not needed. 
It was critical for me to **install the obsolete version of the android Support library (23.2.1).** (which can coexist with the latest version).

Comment: This link might also be useful https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34203

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same error:

> aapt.exe exit with code -1

That means you have probably used or imported some media or an image, and those image names contain characters that conflicts in XML file (because Xamarin and Android use many XML markup style). Just check out all the items you've imported from outside of your project and correct their names (remove all special characters like -+*/_, and that yet)...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to go to Android project's properties and remove `Version Number` and `Package Name` values. I don't know why it worked. If someone could explain, it will help future visitors of this question.

Comment: Having a decimal in the version number was causing the issue for me. Once I removed that, I was able to archive. It appears to be an error with formatting.